# Is there a way to not trigger the init value of the Variable<T>?

Tags: rx-swift

See below code.

```
class ViewController4: UIViewController {
    var disposeBag = DisposeBag()
    let v = Variable(0)

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        v.asObservable()
            .subscribe(onNext: { print($0) })
            .disposed(by: disposeBag)

        v.value = 1
    }
}
```

When it runs, it will print

```
0
1
```

However, I don't want it to run on `0`, or saying `0` is just the value used to initiate `v`. Can I do that? Or I have to postpone the code at the time point when I use it?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You can use operator `.skip` to suppress N first element emited. So in your case `skip(1)` will supress the init value.

> http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/skip

```
v.asObservable().skip(1)
        .subscribe(onNext: { print($0) })
        .disposed(by: disposeBag)

v.value = 1
//Output : 1

v.value = 2
v.value = 3
//Output : 1 2 3
```